# Modify child record (update modified_date and is_delete) when parents' respective values are changed

Tags: mysql

My question is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325801/mysql-change-status-of-all-child-records-if-status-of-parent-is-updated).

Say I have three tables, user, country and user_activity whose schema/table-structure are given below:-

```
|---------------------------------------------|
|   id   |   fname   |  lname   |    status   |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

country:-

```
|--------------------------------|
|   id   |   name   |   status   |
|--------------------------------|
```

user_activity

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id  |  user_id  |  activity_type  |  country_id  |  location  | status | 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Say, I create the user table like this:-

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `iduser` (`id`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, I create the country table like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idcountry` (`id`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to create a table user_activity where the status of user_activity record would change according to the status of user if user_activity.user_id matches user.id

At the same time, if status of user_activity record would change according to the status of country if user_activity.country_id matches country.id.

How can I do that? How can I achieve the objective at the database level, instead of setting it via PHP scripting?

Comment: Let me check if I understood correctly: you want `user_activity.status` to be always the result of the logical expression `user.status AND country.status`?.

Comment: @Dario, yes. That's what I want if possible